# AWS CLI "delete-folder" command help needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a bucket with folder `s3://mybucket/abc/thisFolder` which contains thousands of files inside.

I can use `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/abc/thisFolder --recursive` to delete it and all files inside, and it does it fine one by one.

However, there's also a `delete-folder` command, but to me the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workdocs/delete-folder.html) is not very clear. Its example says `aws workdocs delete-folder --folder-id 26fa8aa4ba2071447c194f7b150b07149dbdb9e1c8a301872dcd93a4735ce65d`

I would like to know what is `workdocs` in example above, and how do I obtain the long `--folder-id` string for my folder `s3://mybucket/abc/thisFolder`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amazon WorkDocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/userguide/what_is.html) is a Dropbox-like service.

If you wish to **delete objects in Amazon S3**, then you should only use AWS CLI commands that start with `aws s3` or `aws s3api`.

Another way to delete folders in Amazon S3 is to configure [Amazon S3 Object lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) with a rule to delete objects with a given prefix. They might take a while to delete (~24 hours), but it will happen automatically rather than one-by-one.